# Changing libgdx preferences location

Tags: java, libgdx, preferences

I'm saving my data in preferances with libgdx, but when I export project to android it doesnt export with preferences. How do I save preferences to project folder location so that when I export my project it goes with it?

```
stats = Gdx.app.getPreferences("Stats");
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you want to do, and want to use the preferences, you can create a class to be in charge, to prove in the first execution of the program if the file exists preferences and if not so, a method that being entrusted to run creating the file. with default preferences.

you could also copy the file you have preferences within the asset folder and read this file and then use `Gdx.files.local ("yourFilesCopy");` to copy/save in this path, it, but I think it would be better to create as I said each first execution.

in this link you can see more, also you can see where the file is saved depending on OS you're using:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences